# Spelling check for a dataframe column in python

Tags: python, dataframe, pycharm

I have a large dataframe consisting of around 10,000 rows of user-inputted data, which have typos. Theres a column with job titles and I would like to search for specific titles, but because of the spelling mistakes I cannot seem to get all the data I need.

Currently what I have is:
titles = [vet, doctor, teacher]

for title in titles:
    targetInfo =[df['jobtitles'].str.contains(title, na=False, case=False)]

Any ideas on how to account for spelling mistakes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you could use the unique function in pandas 
eg:

```
df["titles"].unique()
```

this might help to find the unique values  resulting in the ones containing typos then in excel sheet you can replace those with your preferred ones.